# weird container memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator

I am trying to build my own version of one of the std containers using the linked list method. Every time I get new data I create a new Node and place it in the container. The D'tor will destroy all Nodes when the container it destroyed.

the weird thing is that after a leak check (using valgrind) it says I have a leak every-time I Insert the first data. this is the insert code:

```
template<typename A, typename T>
typename container<A, T>::Iterator Queue<A, T>::insert(
        const A& priority, const T& object) {
    Iterator head = this->begin();
    Iterator tail = this->begin();
    this->findElementPlace(priority, head, tail);
    Node<A, T> *newNode = new Node<A, T>(priority, object);
    head.node->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = (tail.node);
    ++head;
    (this->Psize)++;
    return head;
}
```

it keeps referring me to this line:

```
Node<A, T> *newNode = new Node<A, T>(priority, object);
```

the Node class is very basic:

```
template<typename A, typename T>

class Node {

public:
    Element<A, T> element;
    Node* next;
    Node() :
                element(), next(NULL) {
        }
        Node(const A priority, const T data) :
                element(priority, data), next(NULL) {
        }
        ~Node() {
        }
    };
```

it doesn't matter where the first data is stored, it always says that specific data is not deleted although the D'tor takes care of it. it uses an erase function that erases all elements from the first to the last. this is the main loop:

```
while ((from < to) && (from < this->end())) {
    it.node->next = from.node->next;
    Iterator temp = from;
    ++from;
    delete temp.node;
    (this->Psize)--;
}
```

it deletes all Nodes between the Iterator "from" to Iterator "to" including "from", not including "to"

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Any reason you're not using some form of reference-counted smart pointer, e.g. `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: What does your iterator look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The iterator contains an index parameter and the operator< compares the indexes.
the problem was that each loop "this->end()" was recomputed but the iterators "from" and "to" where not relevant anymore because their indexes weren't relevant anymore.
I added an updating to their indexes so that this time all the elements in the container will be released.
the new erase loop is:

```
while ((from < to) && (from < this->end())) {
    it.node->next = from.node->next;
    Iterator temp = from;
    from.index--;
    ++from;
    delete temp.node;
    (this->Psize)--;
    to.index--;
}
```